# Show image in cell when click and hide image in other cell Swift IOS

Tags: swift, hide, show

First i hide all images in cell. After i click on did select row, in that cell will show image and click again it will hide image. That working. But the problem is when i click on that cell (without click again) and then click other cell, (other cell will show image) but the previous cell will not hide image.

[This code for cell and didselectrow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MDlpm.png)

Comment: Could you add code snippets in your question please?

Comment: I attach image..updated question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

take one variable who contains current show image's indexPath.row value

```
 var showImageIndex : Int?

 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{

   let tableCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cellName") as? CustomCell

   if showImageIndex == indexPath.row{
      tableCell.IBimageView.isHidden = false
   }else{
      tableCell.IBimageView.isHidden = true
   }
 }

 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath){
    showImageIndex = indexPath.row
    self.tableViewName.reload()
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your didSelect method before make anything with your index you need to hidden image in old cell.

this will hide image in your old cell

```
if(index != nil){
    tableView.cellForRow(at:index!) as! FailOrderNoteTableViewCell
    cell.rightViewCell.hidden = true
}
```

And other problem in your code is that you need to set nil for index if you haven't selected cell not row 99 and section 99 that will work fine